# r barplot ylab is horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: r, yaxis

I'm trying to plot a barplot for errors, but my ylab is horizontal and I want to be vertical in the left of the plot.

```
errors=c(7.338711e-07,1.399190e-03,1.666794e-04,2.513632e-04,
       1.888479e-04,1.394840e-03,6.682082e-03,6.471887e-05,
       7.800729e-05,2.087988e-04,3.150596e-03,5.698861e-04,
       5.961718e-04,2.681394e-05,3.202360e-05,3.912834e-04,
       4.910918e-05,6.131810e-05,1.184472e-03,6.525520e-04,
       3.543068e-05,1.816346e-04,1.717658e-04,2.370331e-05,
       8.101786e-05,1.013240e-05,1.511531e-03,3.026940e-04,
       7.963667e-04,5.409863e-04)

ages=60:89

barplot(t(errors),horiz=TRUE,las=2,beside=TRUE,col='orange',xlab="error",ylab=ages)
```

Thank you for your help

The resulting plot is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osdpp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `names.arg` argument, not `ylab`:

```r
barplot(height = errors, 
        names.arg = ages, 
        col = 'orange', 
        xlab = 'error', 
        horiz = TRUE, 
        las = 2, 
        space = .2)
```

[image]

Comment: Pls accept the answer if it did answer your question and upvote it if you find it helpful

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because I don't have enough reputation. I tried several times, but as soon as I upvote, it gets back to 0. Is there a solution for that